# How can I click inside of my window, made with graphics.py, while my in-game timer continues?

Tags: python, for-loop, time, while-loop, timer

I'm creating a program for my class involving creating a simple game with [graphics.py by John Zelles](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py), [definitions that each function within graphics.py can do](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html).

My game basically has a visible timer and counter that checks how many times the window has been clicked. The user is supposed to click in the window to start a 60 second timer. Then, the game will show a number telling the user the amount of times they have to click in the window in order to win the game.

If the timer runs out before the player finishes the amount of clicks, then they lose the game.

However, in my code whenever I click in the window to begin the game, the timer starts but it doesn't display the message telling me how many times I need to click in the window to win the game. It just waits for the timer to finish AND THEN it let's me click inside of the window.

'''

```
def main():

    win = GraphWin('Test', 300, 300)
    win.setBackground("green")

    message = Text(Point(150, 30), "Click to start the game")
    message.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()
    start = True

    sec = 5

    timer = start
    secondsRemain = 5

    for i in range(secondsRemain):
        message.undraw()
        sec -= 1
        message = Text(Point(150, 30), "You have left: " + str(sec+1))
        message.draw(win)
        time.sleep(1)
        if sec == 0:
            message.undraw()
            finalMessage = Text(Point(150, 30), "You LOST!")
            finalMessage.draw(win)
        else:
            continue

     clickCounter = randrange(200)
     while clickCounter > 0:
         clicker = Text(Point(200, 50), "Click the window " + str(clickCounter) +" times!")
         clicker.draw(win)
         win.getMouse()
         clickCounter -= 1
         clicker.undraw()
         if clickCounter == 0:
             eye1.undraw()

     win.getMouse()
     win.close()

main()
```

'''

I also don't want to import any more libraries (if possible). I want to use mostly and only the graphics.py file. And thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of little fixes on this one. By using time.sleep(1) you're essentially causing the script to stop on that line and ignore all the other logic, and then do all the other logic very quickly skipping back to the sleep again. My solution would be to replace that by continuously checking the time with time.time() rather than sleep, so you don't need any other libraries, as you're already using time. Also, by having a loop exterior to another it makes it more complicated to keep a track of when lines are being called, so I replaced it with one for you. I hope this modification to the script below helps you the faster fluttering of the screen I find adds some more urgency.

```
# Edited by Bryce

from graphics import *
from random import *
import time

def main():

    win = GraphWin('Face Hitter!', 300, 300)
    win.setBackground("blue")
    
    clickCounter = randint(50, 100) ## Adjust minimum and maximum for difficulty

    message = Text(Point(150, 30), "Click to start the game")
    clicker = Text(Point(200, 50), "Click the window " + str(clickCounter) +" times!")
    message.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()
    start = True

    initialTime = time.time()
    secondsRemain = 60 ## A full minute


    while (secondsRemain > 0):
        print(secondsRemain)
        secondsRemain = 60 - (time.time() - initialTime) ## Check how long has elapsed since originally checking the time
        message.undraw()
        message = Text(Point(150, 30), "You have left: " + str(secondsRemain))
        message.draw(win)
        if secondsRemain < 0:
            message.undraw()
            finalMessage = Text(Point(150, 30), "You LOST!")
            finalMessage.draw(win)

        clicker.undraw()
        clicker = Text(Point(200, 50), "Click the window " + str(clickCounter) +" times!")
        clicker.draw(win)
        if (win.checkMouse()):
            clicker.undraw()
            clickCounter -= 1
        if clickCounter == 0:
            clicker.undraw()
            clicker = Text(Point(200, 50), "YOU WON!")
            clicker.draw(win)
            #eye1.undraw() ## Remove the # when using it, eye1 wasn't declared in this section of the code so I could test it
            print("Undraw eye - End of game")
            break

    print("Waiting for mouse click to quit...")
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

Good luck with your program Omar!